# Left join table on tbl1.col IN tbl2.col

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have an "IN" statement within a left join clause?
I have two tables with two columns:

```
Table 1:                  Table 2:

Column1:                  Column2:

192192,                   192192
119202                    119202
810395                    810395
975643,                   975643
908574,,                  908574
```

As you can see, tbl1.col1 has entries can have entries with commas trailing or have none at all. I need to join the two tables where column 1 contains column 2 or where they are equal. It made sense to be to join where column1 includes column 2. Maybe there's a better way to accomplish the join?

I need to join the two to access data in table 2. So the columns just need to align while allowing for a potential comma or two in column 1. Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, it might help to specify what flavor of SQL you're using (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc). That way, you can get answers that are relevent to your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just some sort of one-time deal or a staging table and not your real prod table:
(this one works no matter where inteh number the commas are)

```
select <column list>
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on replace(t1.col1, ',','') = t2.col2
```

or

```
select <column list>
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on  cast(t2.col2 as varchar (10)) like t1.col1+'%'
```

(you may or may not need the cast depending onthe data types of the tow columns, I was assuming one was varchar and the other was integer)

or 
(this only works if the value will always be the same length

```
select <column list>
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on left(t1.col1,6) = t2.col2
```

If this is a real prod table, then you could have performance issues joining on a function, so fix the data instead.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't sure if you could perform functions on a column inside the join clause. This is a one time deal because the data was compiled funky for this column.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`rtrim()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php) is perfect for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON trim(t1.col1, ',') = t2.col2;
```

Comment: Right, I am using that for the data, I just wasn't sure if I could perform that function within the join. But yes you're totally correct.

Comment: @phileaton: Yes, basically any expression you could put into a `WHERE` clause, too.

Answer (score 1):

Also you may just want to `substr` function to trim the first table column and use the left outer join as:

using `substr`:

```
 select t1.col1, t2.col2
 from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
 on substr(t1.col1, 0, length(t1.col1)-1) = t2.col2;
```

using `replace`:

```
 select t1.col1, t2.col2
 from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
 on replace(t1.col1, ',' , '')= t2.col2;
```

Both the above queries should work in MySQL and Oracle.